# What does this expression mean when someone is looking up at you ? 覆いかぶさるようなって上目遣いにこちらを見つめてくる

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

When reading i came across this expression ,which i did not understand .Much thanks if anyone can help me find its meaning

**覆いかぶさるようなって上目遣いにこちらを見つめてくるA。**

**(My guess : "A is staring at me ,with her eyes looking up from below which it looks like .... ???" )**

Comment: What does 覆いかぶさる mean?

Comment: `ようなって` -- Is it not よう**に**なって ?

Answer (score 1):

A is staring at me ,with her eyes looking up from below which it looks like A is covering something with his entire body.

> 覆う（おおう）
> cover with something
> かぶさる means to be covered with something
> 覆う+かぶさる　→ 覆いかぶさる　
> (Compound verb 複合動詞)